# Вывод значения в value

Tags: php, yii2, yii, php7

Добрый день!

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему не выводится значение "Привет" в `value` c помощью такого кода:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_sort')->textInput(['maxlength' => true],['value' => 'Привет']) ?>
```

`'maxlength' => true` должно быть в любом случае.

Answer (score 4):

```
$form->field($model, 'id_sort')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'value' => 'Привет'])
```